# Добавлялся class при клике

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так чтобы во всех **span** (их например 6шт на странице) менялся class при клике.

Сейчас меняется только на первом, необходимо на всех сразу и обратно.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#open").click(function() {
    $("#open_w").toggleClass('active')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="open_w" class="scroll"></span>
<span id="open_w" class="scroll"></span>
<span id="open_w" class="scroll"></span>
<span id="open_w" class="scroll"></span>
<div id="open">Открыть</div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' большие спасибки) а то все перепробовал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
     $("#open").click(function() {
         $(".open_w").toggleClass('active')
     });
});
```

```css
.active{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="open_w scroll">1</span>
<span class="open_w scroll">2</span>
<span class="open_w scroll">3</span>
<span class="open_w scroll">4</span>
<div id="open">Открыть</div>
```